# How to create a column that has the count from one table of values in another?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I'm just starting to learn MySQL and relational DBs. I decided to try and build a very simple daily habit tracking db/app for myself as part of the process. I've made progress, in no small part thanks to all the great info here, but I haven't been able to figure this one out. Here are my two tables.

```
habit_log

| id | date  | daily_habit_text | daily_habit_value |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1  | date1 | Good             | 4                 | 
| 2  | date2 | Bad              | 2                 |
| 3  | date3 | OK               | 3                 |
| 4  | date4 | Good             | 4                 |
| 5  | date5 | Great            | 5                 |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

```
habit_values

| habit_value | habit_text |
----------------------------
| 1           | Terrible   | 
| 2           | Bad        |
| 3           | OK         |
| 4           | Good       |
| 5           | Great      |
----------------------------
```

`habit_log` is the table for my daily entries of how I did, which will grow over time. `habit_values` is the table that holds the rating values and text. The `daily_habit_value` column is a foreign key tied to the `habit_value` column.

I'd like a column, either in the `habit_values` table or a new table that shows the count of how many times each `habit_value` appears in the `habit_log` table. I'll then use that for creating a chart. That column needs to update each time a new row is added to the `habit_log` table.

I've tried so many different approaches with counts, joins and foreign keys, but it's all just flailing. I've looked at so many posts but none seem to be specific enough to my requirement, or I just don't know enough to see how they relate. Seeing the solution, or a solution, would really help me see what I'm missing and point me to some things I need to do a deeper learning dive on.

Comment: Why not query from the `habit_log` table drictly when you use the count of appears? If you  calculate and save to a new table, there is a possibility of data inconsistency

Comment: I think the answer to why is simply that I don't know enough to know what I'm doing. I do like the answer given by [seonghun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16596710/seonghun) to run the SQL query nightly (automated) to get the latest counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The SQL query you provided:**

```sql
SELECT
  hv.habit_value,
  hv.habit_text,
  COUNT(hl.id) AS habit_count
FROM
  habit_values hv
LEFT JOIN
  habit_log hl ON hv.habit_value = hl.daily_habit_value
GROUP BY
  hv.habit_value,
  hv.habit_text;
```

This query performs a join between the habit_values and habit_log tables to calculate the occurrence count of each habit_value. It uses a LEFT JOIN to ensure all rows from the habit_values table are included in the result, and it counts the occurrences by matching the daily_habit_value from the habit_log table. The result includes each habit_value, its corresponding habit_text, and the count as habit_count column.

**The trigger-based approach:**

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_habit_count AFTER INSERT ON habit_log
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE habit_values
    SET count = count + 1
    WHERE habit_value = NEW.daily_habit_value;
END;
```

This trigger is executed whenever a new row is inserted into the habit_log table. The trigger references the newly inserted row using the NEW keyword. When triggered, it updates the count value by incrementing it by 1 for the row in the habit_values table that matches the daily_habit_value.

By using this trigger, the count value is automatically updated whenever a new row is added to the habit_log table.

Both approaches achieve the goal of updating the count column in the habit_values table. With the SQL query, you can manually execute the query whenever needed to obtain the latest results. On the other hand, the trigger-based approach ensures that the count value is always up to date by automatically updating it whenever a new row is inserted.

**I thought it would be best to get the values with a SQL query and cache them.**